# How can I show the text clicked?

Tags: angular

I have an empty div and a list of 3 elements underneath it. How can I show the clicked text in the empty div? Thanks

```
<div></div>
<span>link one</span>
<span>link two</span>
<span>link three</span>
```

Comment: <div [innerHTML]="text"><div><span #one (click)="text=one.innerHTML"> link one</span><span #two (click)="text=two.innerHTML"> link two</span>` This is just a shorthand mind it you should create a method to do such operations.

Comment: I figured out. Use $event in HTML and then get the innerHTML via event.target.innerText in typescript. Assign that to a variable which can be inserted into the empty div.

Comment: @Mark I strongly recommend against doing that. Manually Injecting html in Angular is the path to massive issues. None of the angular bootstrapping will take place on injected html. The comment from joyBlanks is a much better suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a variable globally in component

```
 linkValue: string;
```

Then your html should be like

```
    <div style="color:green">{{linkValue}}</div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span (click)="linkValue=$event.target.innerText">link one</span>
    <br/>
    <span (click)="linkValue=$event.target.innerText">link two</span>
    <br/>
    <span (click)="linkValue=$event.target.innerText">link three</span> 
    <br/>
```

[Sample Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aXmiKwF99pUOkkdLm37t?p=preview)

Sorry! After posted this answer ony I saw your comment.

Comment: Thanks. This is the way I used as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Below is HTML code.**

```
    <div>{{selectedLink}}</div>

    <div>
       <span (click)='linkClicked(item.LinkName)' *ngFor="let item of Items"> 
        {{item.LinkName}} 
       </span>
    </div>
```

**and below is the typescript code**

```
    selectedLink: string; // declare global variable 

    //Add this method 
    linkClicked(linkName:string){
     this.selectedLink = linkName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-innerhtml-event-handler-2of6up?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
 myItems=[{name:"link"},{name:"link1"},{name:"link2"},{name:"link3"}]
 selectedLink;
 clickeMe(input) : void{
    console.log('event element',input);
    this.selectedLink=JSON.stringify(input);
  }
```

.html

```
<span>select one</span>

    <div>{{selectedLink}}</div>

    <div>
       <span (click)='clickeMe(item)' *ngFor="let item of myItems"> 
        {{item.name}} 
       </span>
    </div>
```